# Which are the largest planes to have operated on an aircraft carrier?

Tags: landing, takeoff, aircraft-carrier

In 1963, [the C-130](http://www.theaviationzone.com/factsheets/c130_forrestal.asp) was tested by the US Navy for air carrier operations. Have there been any other *comparable* or larger aircraft that have landed and taken off from the deck of an aircraft carrier?

By *large*, I am referring to two parameters: wingspan and weight.

Answer (score 8):

U-2s also [landed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_3WeYXDKQ0) and [took off](http://youtu.be/L8HMPMYL19E?t=2m30s) from aircraft carriers.

Comment: U-2 is neither heavier nor has wider wingspan than C-130

Comment: @JanHudec "...Have there been any other **comparable** or larger aircraft..." ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The KC-130F that performed the trials from the USS Forrestal in 1963 appears to be the largest, I know of nothing else of that size, weight and span that has done it.

Comment: And no arresting hook, as seen in the U-2 video link above

Answer (score 0):

EA-3B, "Whale" the Skywarrier.

Comment: That's the largest aircraft that did regular operations from carriers. The Hercules is larger, but was only used for trials on an empty deck.

Answer (score 0):

The largest aircraft by weight and wingspan is the C-130, and then the U-2 by wingspan and the A-3 Skywarrior by weight. The C-130 was only used for testing to see if it would be possible to use it as a carrier-onboard-delivery (COD) aircraft. The U-2 had one operation mission, but otherwise it was only used to evaluate the possibility of operating it from carriers in order to reach otherwise inaccessible places.

The A-3 is the only one of these to operate routinely from an aircraft carrier, and did so from 1956 until it's retirement (EA-3B) in 1991.